# Why is Docker desktop continuously crashing with error: request returned Internal Server Error for API route and version?

Tags: docker, macos, docker-compose, dockerfile

my docker “crashes” with the error: `request returned Internal Server Error for API route and version ***** check if the server supports the requested API version`

for all microservices im running in my docker-compose. This happens constantly, i might get my services up and running for a few min as longest. so i need to restart docker desktop constantly.

Im running 2 docker-compose.yml files:
`docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build`

the docker-compose.dev.yml file basically just override so it runs my services locally.

Mac OS: 14.4 (23E214) 
Docker desktop: 4.28.0 

**Engine:** 
Version: 25.0.3 
API version: 1.44 (minimum version 1.24)
Go version: go1.21.6
Git commit: f417435
Built: Tue Feb 6 21:14:22 2024
OS/Arch: linux/arm64
Experimental: false

i have tried just running my docker-compose.yml without the docker-compose.dev.yml,
but still get the same error.